# Retrieve TokenResponse using a Google account name

Tags: android, access-token, drive

In my Android application I choose Google account through

```
AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent
```

After that I want use this account to get access to Drive API using access token and refresh token from `TokenResponse` class. But I have no idea how can I get a `TokenResponse` instance using only account name.

How can I provide it?